# NSOpenPanel File URL Format

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring, nsurl, nsopenpanel

I have a NSOpenPanel and I get the URL for the file from it and put it into an NSString like this:

```
imageURL = [[[panel URLs] objectAtIndex: 0] absoluteString];
```

Then when I go to save the file (in the same location as the file was opened) I use this:

```
[imageData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", imageURL, imageName, imageType] atomically:NO];
```

Problem with this is that it won't save to any location with a space in. For example is there was a folder in that path like this:

This Folder

It would be put in the string like this:

This%20Folder

But it of course can't save to that location because its not right. How can I get around this? Possible to get the actual string with no changes? Thanks.

Comment: Is `imageData` an instance of `NSData`, `NSImage` or `NSImageRep`?

Comment: have you tried the `-[NSData writeToURL:atomically:]` method instead? Apple even recommends `NSURL` over `NSString` when dealing with file paths.

Comment: if you retain you should always (auto)release it! Unless you are using garbage collection, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
imageURL = [imageURL stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSAsciiStringEncoding]
```